# Have Thunar remember file ordering for folders

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, settings, thunar, defaults

I often attach files when on the web (using Chrome/Firefox), or when using email (Thunderbird). I need to navigate to a specific folder, and there I often need one of the most recent files.

However, Thunar always resets the "Order by" column to "Name", so for every single attachment I need to re-order the column. This becomes annoying after so many attachments from the same folder.

Is there a way of having Thunar remember the "Sort By" column for a certain folder? And if not, is there a way of setting Thunar to always sort by date? I think I prefer this over the "Name" column, generally.

Using: XFCE, Thunar, Arch Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$EDITOR .config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini`

You are looking for the line `SortColumn` and `SortOrder`

```
SortColumn=modified
SortOrder=descending
```

should give you what you are trying to achieve.